# Get Azure resource using filters

Tags: azure, powershell

i'm trying to use Powershell to query my Storage Accounts by using name filter

I have tried these commands (and their variants) but have not still managed to get this working.

```
Get-AzStorageAccount | where -FilterScript {($_.ResourceType -eq "storageAccounts") -and ($_.StorageAccountName -contains "Prod") }

Get-AzResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts | Get-AzResource -Name Prod* | ft
```

Any tips because I'm a bit lost. My goal would be that command / script would print out e.g all Storage Accounts which contains Prod in their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1) and `-match` to filter here:

```
Get-AzStorageAccount | Where-Object {$_.StorageAccountName -match 'prod'}
```

Or using `-like`:

```
Get-AzStorageAccount | Where-Object {$_.StorageAccountName -like '*prod*'}
```

If you really want to use `Get-AzResource`, then you need to filter by the `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts` resource type:

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'prod'}
```

You can have a look at [Matching Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#matching-operators) from `about_comparison_operators` for more information.